# Is there a reason people prefer using the constructor of a React component instead of componentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I find that using the lifecycle method `componentWillMount` to setup initial state...

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.state = {
    comments: []
  };
}
```

...is slightly simpler than using the constructor. Namely because when you use the constructor you *have* to call `super()`.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    comments: []
  };
}
```

Not only that but if your component is passed `props` and/or `state` then you have to manually pass those through as well.

```
constructor(props, state) {
  super(props, state);
  ...
}
```

I haven't had any problems using `componentWillMount` but I virtually never see anyone using it for setting up state (unless they are avoiding es6 and don't have classes). I get that we have access to the constructor in an es6 class, but why use it when you have to wire a manual passthrough to the parent constructor and there is a perfectly good lifecycle method ready and waiting so you don't have to do that?

Just curious if there was an actual practical reason or if it's mostly just preference.

Comment: you could also just use class properties and avoid initialising state in either of them

Comment: Dear close-voter: It's not "opinion-based" unless the answer is literally "it's opinion-based" because my actual question is whether or not there is a **practical** reason for choosing one or the other.

Comment: @LinasMickevicius I'm not sure what you mean there. Mind expanding on that?

Comment: You can do this: `state = { comments: [] }` inside of your class

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. I rather like that actually...

Comment: Only problem I potentially see there is propagating an initial value passed through `props` onto the state. Would this still work on the class `state = { showing: this.props.showing }`? I'm inclined to think 1. `this` won't refer to the instance of our class yet, and 2. `this.props` may not even be defined yet.

Comment: yes it would work

Comment: I just tried this and babel got angry at trying to initialize properties this way. https://i.imgur.com/5snd2J7.png

Comment: You need to install "transform-class-properties" plugin

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constructor is the only "correct" place to initialize (directly assign to) `state`. i.e. `this.state = {...}`

The rest of the functions you define within the component (`componentWillMount`, etc.) are so called "lifecycle callbacks" invoked by the React engine. It is expected that `state` should be immutable throughout the lifetime of the component and must never be directly assigned to. Instead, you'd have to `this.setState({...})` in order to effect any changes to the `state` anywhere outside the constructor.

While your current practice may not so far have caused any issues, it's not guaranteed to continue working in the same way. If for some reason React reads `state` between lifecycle callbacks, and you have mutated it in your `componentWillMount` callback, this may create unintended consequences.

My advice would be to only ever directly initialize `state` in your constructor, and use `setState` everywhere else.

If verbosity is a concern and you have no other purpose for the constructor than initializing your `state`, and you don't need the `props` to initialize your `state`, simply declare and initialize your state property:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {}
}
```

Comment: Okay this makes sense. I appreciate the thorough answer.

Comment: re: your edit --> It appears that referencing `this.props` inside the class property initializer actually does work. `state = { showing: this.props.showing }` I just tested it. I am surprised it does though tbh.

Comment: Interesting! I'd still stay away from doing that. My guess is that the reason `this.props` was available is because the `super()` constructor was called first and added it to the instance, and it was available to you during `state` initialization. Now, if you end up creating a constructor of your own, the order of property initializations may change, and `props` may no longer have been initialized outside of your constructor. Keep your code as predictable as possible. Out-of-constructor property initialization that assumes and accesses another property sounds risky and error-prone to me :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. A bit of googling has found me a couple articles stating to do exactly that with class property initialization. [This one](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/06/14/react-and-es6-part2.html) actually *does* recommend calling `this.props` from within the initializer. So I don't know what to think lol. Sounds like class property initialization hasn't fully been standardized yet as well so maybe it's best to just go back to constructor for now anyway.

Comment: PS - I did just test re-adding a constructor while still using property initialization and it didn't hurt anything as far as I'm aware. Initializer still pulled `props` value properly. I agree with you though, that accessing other properties from a property initializer just doesn't feel right. I'm betting that's a behavior that changes at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Well according to the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount):

> Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead.

It also mentioned that:

> This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering.

So i guess this could be part of the reason.